# How to use cout in macro c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-preprocessor

I have following macro for measuring time in header file:

```
#define TIMER_START(x) double ___timer__##x = (double) getTickCount(); 
#define TIMER_END(x) ___timer__##x = (getTickCount() - ___timer__##x) *1000 /  getTickFrequency(); cout << "t" << ##x << ": " << ___timer__##x << endl;
```

The problem is, when I use this header file, the cout is not defined. Is there any option to use it this way? I have tried specifiing namespace but with no luck. Either ostream:: and std:: doesn't contain definition for cout.

PS: I'm working in MSVS2010.

Comment: Measuring time in header file? Do you mean code execution time of some functions that are defined in a header file?

Comment: why does this have to be a marco?

Comment: You need to include `<iostream>` which defines `cout` and the `std` namespace.

Comment: @crashmstr The header contains only the macro. The measuring is done in code later.

111111 Well I a bit lazy to copy&paste those lines over and over again. It for debug purposes only.

PeterWood Thanks, thats what I was "afraid" of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `cout` has to be visible at the point where you invoke the macro.  Writing

```
TIMER_START(0);
```

is just like writing

```
double ___timer__0 = (double) getTickCount();;
```

and the same visibility rules apply.

I suspect that changing `cout` to `std::cout` will fix the problem.  Of course you'll need to include the appropriate header in any source file that invokes the macro.

Some other issues:

Identifiers starting with underscores are reserved to the implementation.  I believe C++ also reserves identifiers with embedded double underscores.  You're trying to avoid colliding with user-defined identifiers, but you risk colliding with compiler-defined or library-defined identifiers.  It's probably not going to cause any visible problems, but you should use some other unique prefix.

The trailing semicolons in your macro definitions are redundant; you'll provide those when you invoke them:

```
TIMER_START(0);
TIMER_END(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, for info. I will do the necessary tweaks.